# how to add wp nonce to simple ajax function in wordpress

Tags: jquery, ajax, wordpress

i'm trying to make the simple plugins with ajax in wp, and i was make the button such as "like" for posts with support of some peoples

my problem
1.
i was find a solution to secure it with nonce, but i refer many in google but not success.

my link when i view code :

```
<a class="love-button" href="http://localhost/topaco/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=post_love_add_love&amp;post_id=243" data-id="243">give like for pơst</a>
```

2.
I can double click, 3 clicks, 4 clicks and more, the number are Continuous increase if i click to the button.

how to limit one click for one session or set the times user can click to increase the number.

## here is my code,

## in php plugins file :

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'ajax_test_enqueue_scripts' );
function ajax_test_enqueue_scripts() {
    if( is_single() ) {
        wp_enqueue_style( 'love', plugins_url( '/love.css', __FILE__ ) );
    }
    wp_enqueue_script( 'love', plugins_url( '/love.js', __FILE__ ), array('jquery'), '1.0', true );
    wp_localize_script( 'love', 'postlove', array(
        'ajax_url' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ),
    ));
}
add_filter( 'the_content', 'post_love_display', 99 );
function post_love_display( $content ) {

    //check_ajax_referer( 'thienduc', 'security' );

    $love_text = '';

    if ( is_single() ) {

        $love = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'post_love', true );
        $love = ( empty( $love ) ) ? 0 : $love;

        $love_text = '<p class="love-received"><a class="love-button" href="' . admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php?action=post_love_add_love&post_id=' . get_the_ID() ) . '" data-id="' . get_the_ID() . '">give love</a><span id="love-count">' . $love . '</span></p>'; 
    }
    return  $love_text . $content;
}
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_post_love_add_love', 'post_love_add_love' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_post_love_add_love', 'post_love_add_love' );
function post_love_add_love() {
    $love = get_post_meta( $_REQUEST['post_id'], 'post_love', true );
    $love++;
    update_post_meta( $_REQUEST['post_id'], 'post_love', $love );
    if ( defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) && DOING_AJAX ) { 
        echo $love;
        die();
    }
    else {
        wp_redirect( get_permalink( $_REQUEST['post_id'] ) );
        exit();
    }
}
```

=============================

## and JS file

```
jQuery( document ).on( 'click', '.love-button', function() {
    var post_id = jQuery(this).data('id');
    jQuery.ajax({
        url : postlove.ajax_url,
        type : 'post',
        data : {
            action : 'post_love_add_love',
            post_id : post_id,
        },
        success : function( response ) {
            jQuery('#love-count').html( response );
        }
    });

    return false;
})
```

---

Answer (score 1):

You can use cookies like this:

```
$cookie_name = "liked-" . get_the_ID();
$cookie_value = get_the_ID();

if(!isset($_COOKIE[$cookie_name])) {
    // Fire like action here and set cookie

setcookie($cookie_name, $cookie_value, time() + (86400 * 30), "/"); // keep it for a month
} else {
    // Do something, if post is already liked
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your opinion, but how to add nonce to url. :)

Answer (score 0):

In case you or someone need the answer about adding nonce.

1- Add nonce to wp_localize_script:

```
wp_localize_script( 'love', 'postlove', array(
    'ajax_url' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ),
    'security' => wp_create_nonce( 'love-nonce' ),
));
```

2- Add [check_ajax_referer()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/check_ajax_referer) to your function:

```
function post_love_add_love() {
  check_ajax_referer( 'love-nonce' );
  // Your code ...
}
```

3- Add nonce to your JS code (data block):

```
data : {
    action : 'post_love_add_love',
    post_id : post_id,
    security: postlove.security,
},
```

As for second part, you can use @Ali_k solution.